# No Primary partition

Tags: dual-boot

I have just installed ubuntu and during installation, I have set all the partitions as logical even the swap and root. Will it cause any problem later. I have windows dual boot system.

Comment: Ubuntu can work from logical partitions. Sometimes there's no other way, like when you have 3 primary partitions already in a "msdos" partitioned drive.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will not cause any problem later.